# Warning message while rendering LaTeX in Inkscape

Tags: python, 22.04, latex, 22.10, inkscape

I installed `pdflatex-full`.

When I try to export a math expression using LaTeX in Inkscape 1.1 (with **Extension -> Render -> Mathematics -> LaTeX (pdflatex)** (in Inkscape 1.2, it is `Extensions -> Render -> Formula (pdflatex)`)), I get the following warning message.

```
/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/command.py:73: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
  from distutils.spawn import find_executable
```

Since I am not using Python 3.12 (This issue is present on Ubuntu 22.04 and 22.10), this warning is does not help much, and it is extremely annoying when I need to generate many LaTeX expressions in Inkscape.

How to suppress this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This workaround is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/879249) answer.

Open the file `/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/command.py`, and add the following lines after python imports `os` and `system`.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```

Restart Inkscape, and the problem should be gone (unless the file is rewritten by a future update of Inkscape).